# Puzzled over the behavior of Pandas in groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataset which has among others a binary variable:

```
Transactions['has_acc_id_and_cus_id'].value_counts()
1    1295130
0     823869
Name: has_acc_id_and_cus_id, dtype: int64
```

When I groupby this dataset --Transactions-- using this particular binary variable as one grouping variable I get a grouped dataset --df100-- that has only one level of the aforementioned binary variable.

```
df100 = Transactions.groupby(['acc_reg_year', 'acc_reg_month', 'year', 'month',\
                              'has_acc_id_and_cus_id'])[['net_revenue']].agg(['sum', 'mean', 'count'])

df100['has_acc_id_and_cus_id'].value_counts()
1    1421
Name: has_acc_id_and_cus_id, dtype: int64
```

Comment: `has_acc_id_and_cus_id` should not be a column in the `groupby`, it's an index. I'm surprised that line doesn't throw an `AttributeError`

Comment: You don't need `\ `, line continuation is implicit inside brackets.

Comment: @Josh Yes you are right. I reset the index but for reasons of brevity I did not include the command. Sorry if this was bad practice after all.

Comment: Its useful to show *exactly* what code you've used and the exact output otherwise people get misled in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to just `groupby` on `has_acc_id_and_cus_id` then the command you want will be...

```
df100 = Transactions[['has_acc_id_and_cus_id', 'net_revenue']].groupby(['has_acc_id_and_cus_id']).agg(['sum', 'mean', 'count'])
```

This subsets just the variable you want to summarise by (`has_acc_id_and_cus_id`) and the variable you wish to summarise (`net_revenue`)...

```
Transactions[['has_acc_id_and_cus_id', 'net_revenue']]
```

...you then group these by `has_acc_id_and_cus_id`...

```
Transactions[['has_acc_id_and_cus_id', 'net_revenue']].groupby('has_acc_id_and_cus_id')
```

...before you then apply the `agg()` function to get the desired statistics.

The mistake you made, based on your stated aim of summarising by `has_acc_id_and_cus_id` alone, was having four other variables you were grouping by (`acc_reg_year`, `acc_reg_month`, `year` and `month`).

If you do actually want the summary by `has_acc_id_and_cus_id` *within* all the others then your original code was correct, but perhaps there are missing values in one or more of `acc_reg_year`, `acc_reg_month`, `year` and `month` when `has_acc_id_and_cus_id == 0`, so check your data...

```
Transactions[Transactions[`has_acc_id_and_cus_id`] == 0][[`acc_reg_year`, `acc_reg_month`, `year`, `month`]].head(100)
```